# Splitting column of a really big dataframe in two (or more) new cols

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, large-data

### Problem

Hey there! I'm having some trouble trying to split one column of my dataframe in two (or even more) new columns. I think this depends on the fact that the dataframe I'm working with comes from a really big csv file, almost 10gb worth of space. Once it is loaded into a Pandas dataframe, this is represented by ~60mil of rows and 5 cols.

### Example

Initially, the dataframes looks something like this:

```
In [1]: df
Out[1]: 
               category  other_col
0            animal.cat          5
1            animal.dog          3
2  clothes.shirt.sports          6
3           shoes.laces          1
4                  None          0
```

I want to first remove the rows of the df for which the category is not defined (i.e., the last one), and then split the category column in three new columns based on where the dot appears: one for the main category, one for the first subcategory and another one for the last subcategory (if that actually exists). Finally, I want to merge the whole dataframe back together.

In other words, this is what I want to obtain:

```
In [2]: df_after
Out[2]: 
   other_col main_cat sub_category_1 sub_category_2
0          5   animal            cat           None
1          3   animal            dog           None
2          6  clothes          shirt         sports
3          1    shoes          laces           None
```

### My approach

My approach for this was the following:

```
df = df[df['category'].notnull()]

df_wt_cat = df.drop(columns=['category'])

df_cat_subcat = df['category'].str.split('.', expand=True).rename(columns={0: 'main_cat', 1: 'sub_category_1', 2: 'sub_category_2', 3: 'sub_category_3'})

df_after = pd.concat([df_wt_cat, df_cat_subcat], axis=1)
```

which seems to work just fine with small datasets, but it sucks up too much memory when this is applied on a dataframe that big and the Jupyter kernel just dies.

I've tried to read the dataframe in chunks, but I'm not really sure how should I proceed after that; I've obviously tried searching this kind of problem here on stack overflow, but I didn't manage to find anything useful.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

`split` and `join` methods do the job:

```
results = df['category'].str.split(".", expand = True))
df_after = df.join(results)
```

after doing that you can freely filter resulting dataframe

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But isn't this exactly what I told I tried? Apart from the join, I mean. But problem remains, since I did the exact same thing: the dataset is too big to do this and kernel just dies when applied on it.

Comment: For scaling issues you should probably use dask (https://dask.org)

Comment: Can you elaborate a little bit on how to do exactly this task with dask? I've never used it, so I'm not really sure on how to proceed.

Comment: Citing tasks common uses: "Dask DataFrame is used in situations where Pandas is commonly needed, usually when Pandas fails due to data size or computation speed:
- Manipulating large datasets, even when those datasets don’t fit in memory
- Accelerating long computations by using many cores
- Distributed computing on large datasets with standard Pandas operations like groupby, join, and time series computations". Dask DataFrame copies the Pandas API, and allows you to split dataset along axis, later it relies on parallelism as it is less bound to GIL (global interpreter lock).